# How to locate that folder and files content related to every process newly started

Tags: process

According to my knowledge when we start a process. A folder related to that process is created somewhere else, and that folder have 2 sub-folders and then those sub-folders have sub-files.

My question is that where that folder, sub-folders and sub-files are present and what is content inside sub-files and what is purpose of that files??

Thank you in advance. Waiting for answer!!!

Comment: I have no clue what your question is about.

Comment: vanadium when we run a process any file related to it where formed in directories only give me its clue

Comment: You nevertheless want to clarify your question: what is your goal? What do you want to know specifically?

Comment: I have to write a program in C when i run that program that program will create directory with process name in UNIX.  My task is to identify that directory and where that directory creates as well as what directory contains.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer given below about the `/proc` filesystem? Your question is still very unclear. In the post you write the directories are created "automatically" but now you write your C program creates them as if you have put some `mkdir` command in the C program. What is it then?

Comment: when i run some process let's suppose i will make a process of running for loop 1000 times. and make some child processes using fork system call. When I execute that program is their any directory created against that process????

Answer (score 3):

You are probably talking about the /proc filesystem:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Normally though you don't have to interact with it.

If you want to get the process ID of your application from within your application so you can locate the right directory, you can use e.g. getpid() in C:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t my_PID = getpid(void);
```

See also
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html

Comment: when i run some process let's suppose i will make a process of running for loop 1000 times. and make some child processes using fork system call. When I execute that program is their any directory created against that process????

Comment: You do not need to care about that, the operating system does all that in the background.

Comment: i know that os will do but my task is to find that directory if you know kindly tell me?

Comment: Read the link in my answer and it should be clear. If you want to know what process ID your application gets and use that from within your application, I'm sure there's a function in C that can get that ID, but I can't tell from the top of my head.

Comment: Added information to the original answer.